# Page navigation using HubTiles, PRISM, and MVVM on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone, prism

I'm trying to use the HubTile control from the WPToolkit, PRISM, and MVVM design. My problem is navigating pages.

MainPageModel

```
private string _navigationUri;
        public string NavigationUri
        {
            get { return _navigationUri; }
            set
            {
                if (_navigationUri != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging();
                    _navigationUri = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

MainPageViewModel

```
        private void Navigate(string s)
    {
        (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri(s, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

        private DelegateCommand<string> _hubTileTap;
    public DelegateCommand<string> HubTileTap
    {
        get { return _hubTileTap; }
    }

_hubTileTap = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
```

XAML

```
<DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:HubTile 
                            Margin="10"
                            Size="Default"
                            Title="{Binding Title}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.HubTileTap}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding NavigationUri}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </toolkit:HubTile>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

Putting in a breakpoint, I can see that my method never actually fires. Also, honestly, I'm not 100% certain that I set things up the right way to pass the string from the HubTile object to the DelegateCommand and then to the Method.

I'm very new to MVVM, PRISM, and still a noob at programming. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What does data template live in?  Do you have a collection of tiles?  The context of the template is the item usually.  So, where Title lives is where the command will fire.

edit: what you added, DataContext.HubTileTap won't work, inside the template, DataContext is the item.

One possible way to do this in with prism is to put an action on the item class.  Then when you create the items, set the action of each item to your tap method.

```
public class EmptyClass
    {
        public ObservableCollection<HubTileItem> HubTiles { get; set; }

        public EmptyClass()
        {
            HubTiles = new ObservableCollection<HubTileItem>();
            HubTiles.Add(new HubTileItem { Title = "Tile1", HubTileTap = () => HubTileTap() };);
        }

        public void HubTileTap()
        {
        }
    }

    public class HubTileItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public Action HubTileTap { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Data template is inside of a listbox. And yes, I have a collection of tiles. 3 of them that do show up when I run the app. Tapping them does nothing.

Comment: What is the items source for the list box?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1889e331-9973-4f30-9b45-4e2323ac84ee/mvvm-prism-button-with-commandsclick-inside-a-datatemplate

Comment: It is binded to my HubTile observable collection.

Comment: The items in that collection is where the binding is looking for HubTileTap.

Comment: Ah. Right. Well I changed it to DataContext.HubTileTap, but that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Widows Phone doesn't support FindAncestor for the relative source binding.  I'm not sure how to do this in prism.  In MvvmLight one way is to bind to the static resource in the ViewModelLocator.

Comment: Hm. Okay. Well I have been basing my code off of someone that made an example for me, so I will have to wait for him to wake up I guess. :(  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks for trying. That didn't fix it, though. :(

Comment: Need to see more code then.  Like the ListBox XAML because something else is wrong.